# Submitting AngularJS forms with Bootstrap modals

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having some trouble submitting a form in a Bootstrap modal using AngularJS. The user is currently able to mash the submit button a few times before the modal dismisses and call the submit function each time. This is obviously not desired behaviour.

So I tried adding `data-ng-disabled` to the button, and disabling it when the submit button is clicked. This works correctly and the user cannot submit more than once. But now the modal does not close, even using `data-dismiss="modal"` with the button. I've read about AngularUI Bootstrap but if there's a way to fix this without changing my modals that would be great.

A snipper of the submit button in the modal:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-ng-disabled="isDisabled" ng-click="disableButton(); submit()">Submit</button>
     <button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

The `disableButton()` function:

```
$scope.disableButton = function(){
     $scope.isDisabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You mean to say when user clicks on 'Cancel' button the modal is not closing? Or you want to close modal even on click of submit button.

Comment: Yes, I think that should be default behaviour, when the user submits a form the modal window should close automatically.

Comment: You can do that in-controller as well. After the request is completed successfully, you can close modal from controller also. You can try it.

Comment: Do you mean by using AngularUI `$modal` service?

Comment: Could you give me an example of using the service without changing all my modals to the AngularUI structure?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the name of your form  and use that for ng-disabled, then use the $invalid Input State validation, see below:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
```